# How would we name our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

There is a "tradition" to name chat rooms so they don't have the same name as the sites they belong to.

Our [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22025/woodworking) name is currently boring "Woodworking". How would we name it? Please provide suggestions by answering (one suggestion per answer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's rather simple, but anyway:

### The Workshop

Comment: I'd put a "The" in front, but +1.

Comment: @El'end Yeah, I knew it was missing *something* :D

Comment: I like it... short, simple, and accurate.

Comment: Given the clear lead this answer has over the next one, I've gone ahead and renamed the room.

Comment: I like it!  That's where I like to spend MY time!  ;)

Answer (score 6):

Also for consideration:

### The Lumber Yard

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

### Measure Twice

Answer (score 3):

Per request:

"As the Bowl Turns"

Answer (score 2):

How about ***Sharpening the Saw***?

Answer (score 1):

Gathering Dust

<sub>sawdust, specifically</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **Shop Talk** or **Talking Shop**?